# Chrome -Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, preventdefault

I get this error in Chrome Console and a the same error will continuously generate.

```
[Intervention] Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive. See <URL>
```

[image]